# Firebase api initialization failure Ionic Framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework, firebase

I was trying to use firebase in my Ionic Framework. I added `google-services.json` for android and `GoogleService-Info.plist` for iOS. No other code was added to do initialisation.

I'm able to receive the unique device token on iOS but not on Android. I checked the log and it logs `firebase API initialisation failure` which is crashing the app. Attaching the log, please assist.

```
06-25 09:06:34.798: D/FirebaseApp(17204): com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204): Firebase API initialization failure.
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204): Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/todevs.com.collegemate-2/base.apk)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:34.805: E/FirebaseApp(17204):   ... 20 more
06-25 09:06:34.808: D/FirebaseApp(17204): com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
06-25 09:06:34.823: I/FA(17204): App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
06-25 09:06:34.823: I/FA(17204): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
06-25 09:06:34.852: D/FirebaseApp(17204): Initialized class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.
06-25 09:06:34.852: I/FirebaseInitProvider(17204): FirebaseApp initialization successful
06-25 09:06:34.864: V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(17204): MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
06-25 09:06:34.876: D/XWalkLib(17204): Pre init xwalk core in todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.881: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.882: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve method setValue to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.882: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.882: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve method setValue to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.882: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.882: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve method setValue to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.882: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.882: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve method setValue to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.889: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.900: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaResourceClient to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.900: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve method setResourceClient to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.901: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaUiClient to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.902: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve method setUIClient to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.906: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve method setXWalkViewInternalVisibility to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.906: D/XWalkLib(17204): Reserve method setSurfaceViewVisibility to todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity
06-25 09:06:34.976: D/OpenGLRenderer(17204): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-25 09:06:35.012: V/StatusBar(17204): StatusBar: initialization
06-25 09:06:35.037: D/FCMPlugin(17204): ==> FCMPlugin initialize
06-25 09:06:35.039: D/AndroidRuntime(17204): Shutting down VM
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204): Process: todevs.com.collegemate, PID: 17204
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/todevs.com.collegemate-2/base.apk)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(Unknown Source)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPlugin.initialize(FCMPlugin.java:34)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(CordovaPlugin.java:57)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:172)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:98)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:87)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.init(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:116)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:144)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:214)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at todevs.com.collegemate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
06-25 09:06:35.039: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: I have the same issue, any findings ?

Comment: No couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the plugin and made it working for ionic on both Android and iOS.
https://github.com/guyromb/cordova-plugin-fcm-plus

Make sure you have the latest Xcode, or SDK tools for Android (incl. Google play/services).

Answer (score 0):

go to **project.properties** file ->

try updating your dependency to compile

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2
```

&

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2
```

I believe this bug was fixed in the patches between 9.0.0 and 9.0.2